# How do HTTP proxies deal with external JS files called from HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, proxy, squid

With a HTTP proxy server, I understand that the request goes to the proxy, the proxy makes a new request to the target site, then copies the response and creates HTML markup to display to user accordingly. But what about if there are external javascript files included in the markup of the response (from the target site):

```
<script src="http://externalsite.com/whatever.js"></script>
```

I was expecting them to be re-written in markup displayed to the user by the proxy as :

```
<script src="http://proxy.com/currentusercache/whatever.js"></script>
```

So now I am totally confused!

Comment: The proxy just returns data for the given resource path *when the request for the resource is made* to the proxy. That's all - the client never needs to know the difference and the proxy does not rewrite the original resource paths. (Some anonymizer proxies do, but that's a different topic! Squid is a predominately a caching proxy, not an anonymizing proxy.)

Comment: @user2246674 - so what would happen if it was an anonymizing proxy?

Comment: It depends. An anyonymizing proxy generally goes through great lengths to rewrite any HTML *that it has served* such that all resource paths will use said proxy or other anonymization service. That is, even links to `http://google.com?q=blahblah` might be rewritten to `http://proxy/ASddfad789FD/whatever`. (The proxy still can't affect the original HTML, however - only the HTML that it returns.)

Answer (score 1):

As I know proxy servers does not rewrite urls. 
But the url does not matter if it is relative, then proxied page will connect to proxy again.

But there is some ways to change response body ex. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule if you are using nginx.

PS. You can check [similar mailinglist post](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,138048,138048#msg-138048)